# Software to detect "moving objects" in series of images

Tags: open-source

Hi is there any open software that can track movement of cells from image to image. I have time lapse images that showed the cells. From image to image, the cells are moving here and there. I am interested to detect each cell's position in those series of images. I have tried "cellprofiler" ,"celltracker", "celltrack", "quimp" software etc, but the results generated are not very reliable. Can anyone recommend any good software that can detect position of moving object from series of time lapse images. The software should be able to correlate the object correctly between images. Or any guidance to write own script is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Any OS preference?

Answer (score 4):

The algorithmic technique is reffered to as "Optical flow" and has an implementation in openCV http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html#gsc.tab=0

You can pick points of interest and track them as they move through some footage.

This is often used in video editing tools like [nuke](https://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/nuke/) or [adobe premier pro](http://www.adobe.com/nz/products/premiere.html) for things like camera stabilization and adding elements that move with the footage and appear as part the original